# How to implement for 10 lines and 79 characters in each line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

There is a variable which can have a maximum of 10 lines and each line can have a maximum of 79 characters. Beyond, 10th line and beyond 79th character of each line, nothing should get displayed. How to implement this in perl. I have no idea for how to implement for 10 lines. Can anybody help me out with this ? I am not finding any solution for the same.

The code for counting the number of characters will be :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $string = "As a describer of life and manners, he must be allowed to stand perhaps the first of the first rank. His humour, which, as Steele observes, is peculiar to himself, is so happily diffused as to give the grace of novelty to domestic scenes and daily occurrences. He never "o'ersteps the modesty of nature," nor raises merriment or wonder by the violation of truth. His figures neither divert by distortion nor amaze by aggravation. He copies life with so much fidelity that he can be hardly said to invent; yet his exhibitions have an air so much original, that it is difficult to suppose them not merely the product of imagination"

if(length($string) > 79)
{
    $string = substr($string,0,79);
} 

print "my string is :",$string;
```

But for , lines how to check ? and How to club it with lines code ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: I don't know.. Maybe count till 79th character before \n and count \n in general so that when you see number 10 you can drop everything else ? hm ?

Comment: @dgw : I don't know that why I have asked here.

Comment: Your variable has one line of somewhere around 600 characters.  Are you meant to chop that to just the first 79 characters, or are you meant to split it into 8 lines?  Should the chopping or splitting be done at word boundaries or at character positions? Are you intended to assign the value back to the string with embedded newlines?  Or are you just supposed to print the data in up to 10 lines of up to 79 characters each (plus newline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the string split at word boundaries and reformatted so that internal newlines are treated as blanks and that you want to print at most 10 lines each with at most 79 characters plus the newline, then this code seems to do the job. Note that the string in the question contains both single and double quotes, so I used `q{}` to delimit the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant MAXLINELEN => 79;
use constant MAXNUMLINES => 10;

my $string = q{As a describer of life and manners, he must be allowed to stand perhaps the first of the first rank. His humour, which, as Steele observes, is peculiar to himself, is so happily diffused as to give the grace of novelty to domestic scenes and daily occurrences. He never "o'ersteps the modesty of nature," nor raises merriment or wonder by the violation of truth. His figures neither divert by distortion nor amaze by aggravation. He copies life with so much fidelity that he can be hardly said to invent; yet his exhibitions have an air so much original, that it is difficult to suppose them not merely the product of imagination};

sub print_up_to_10_lines_of_79_chars_split_at_words
{
    my($string) = @_;

    my(@words) = split /\s+/, $string;
    my $line_num = 0;
    my $line_len = 0;
    my $pad = "";
    foreach my $word (@words)
    {
        my $len = length($word);
        if ($line_len + length($pad) + $len > MAXLINELEN)
        {
            last if (++$line_num >= MAXNUMLINES);
            print "\n";
            $pad = "";
            $line_len = 0;
        }
        printf "%s%s", $pad, $word;
        $line_len += length($pad) + $len;
        $pad = " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}

print "First string: (", length($string), ")\n";
print_up_to_10_lines_of_79_chars_split_at_words($string);

$string .= ". $string.";
print "Second string: (", length($string), ")\n";
print_up_to_10_lines_of_79_chars_split_at_words($string);
```

Sample output:

```
First string: (629)
As a describer of life and manners, he must be allowed to stand perhaps the
first of the first rank. His humour, which, as Steele observes, is peculiar to
himself, is so happily diffused as to give the grace of novelty to domestic
scenes and daily occurrences. He never "o'ersteps the modesty of nature," nor
raises merriment or wonder by the violation of truth. His figures neither
divert by distortion nor amaze by aggravation. He copies life with so much
fidelity that he can be hardly said to invent; yet his exhibitions have an air
so much original, that it is difficult to suppose them not merely the product
of imagination
Second string: (1261)
As a describer of life and manners, he must be allowed to stand perhaps the
first of the first rank. His humour, which, as Steele observes, is peculiar to
himself, is so happily diffused as to give the grace of novelty to domestic
scenes and daily occurrences. He never "o'ersteps the modesty of nature," nor
raises merriment or wonder by the violation of truth. His figures neither
divert by distortion nor amaze by aggravation. He copies life with so much
fidelity that he can be hardly said to invent; yet his exhibitions have an air
so much original, that it is difficult to suppose them not merely the product
of imagination. As a describer of life and manners, he must be allowed to stand
perhaps the first of the first rank. His humour, which, as Steele observes, is
```

If your requirements differ from the assumptions I stated, then obviously the code has to be changed, but you have to state your requirements precisely.  It would, for example, be perfectly feasible to build an answer string that, given a long input, contains the output rather than printing to standard output.  If your splitting requirements are different, the processing will be different.

Answer (score 1):

[`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) can be used to truncate a string:

```
printf "%.79s", $string; # Limit the string to 79 characters
```

To print only 10 lines you'll need to employ a [loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control) of some kind. Here's an example using a [`foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loop and a counter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = ...;

my $line_num = 0;
for my $line (@lines) {
    last if ++$line_num > 10; # Increment counter and exit loop after 10th line
    printf "%.79s", $line;
}
```

Alternatively, use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to only take 10 lines:

```
for my $line (splice @lines, 10) {
    printf "%.79s", $line;
}
```

Comment: why your code is just printing first line. Not the complete 10 lines. Thank you so much for the help! Could you help me out this problem also.

Comment: How are you defining a line? Are you wanting to split `$string` into sentences and print the first 10? Maybe you could provide expected output in the question.